# How does the class_weight parameter in model.fit_generator work with data generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generator

I am trying to use keras to fit a CNN model to classify 2 classes of data . I have imbalanced dataset I want to balance the data. How I can do that ?? , I don't know how to use `class_weight` with my code to have balanced dataset.

Any help would be appreciated.

**code:**

```
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75),
          validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, start=75),
          steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*25))),
          validation_steps=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*75))),
          verbose=2, epochs=15, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[callback])

def generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):
    while True:
        from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
        to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
        for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
            f=paths[i]
            x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f)
            x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
            if('P' in f):
                y = np.repeat([[0,1]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            else:
                y =np.repeat([[1,0]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            yield(x,y)
```

Comment: You have asked the same question three times, that is not acceptable, please stop asking the same question over and over,

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I am sorry for this duplication. But No one answer me. I still have the problem.

Comment: That is not a valid reason to create new questions, make the question clearer, try to attract people to answer you. You can always edit your questions. Note that posting duplicate questions can get you banned from this site.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I understood. Thanks a lot for understanding my situation and for clearance to me .